# How to save an get two, or more variables with java Preferences

Tags: java, variables, get, save, preferences

I don't know how to save three variables, and retrieve each one.
As a result, only the last variable is saved.

Here is my code:

```
public class DatabaseParameters extends javax.swing.JPanel {

private static final String DB_URL = "";

private static final String DB_USERNAME = "";

private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "";

    //Creates new form DatabaseParameters
    public DatabaseParameters() {
        initComponents();
        jButtonDbLogin.setForeground(Color.black);
        jTextFieldDatabaseUrl.setText(readPreferenceDbUrl());
        jTextFieldDatabaseUsername.setText(readPreferenceDbUsername());
        jPasswordDatabasePassword.setText(readPreferenceDbPassword());
    }
    
    // Save data
    public void savePreferences(String dbUrl, String dbUsername, String dbPassword) {
        Preferences prefsDbUrl = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(DatabaseParameters.class);
        Preferences prefsDbUsername = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(DatabaseParameters.class);
        Preferences prefsDbPassword = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(DatabaseParameters.class);

        prefsDbUrl.put(DB_URL, dbUrl);
        prefsDbUsername.put(DB_USERNAME, dbUsername);
        prefsDbPassword.put(DB_PASSWORD, dbPassword);
    }
    
    // Read dbUrl
    public static String readPreferenceDbUrl() {
        Preferences prefsDbUrl = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(DatabaseParameters.class);

        return  prefsDbUrl.get(DB_URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/");
    }
    
    // Read dbUsername
    public static String readPreferenceDbUsername() {
        Preferences prefsDbUsername = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(DatabaseParameters.class);

        return  prefsDbUsername.get(DB_USERNAME, "root");
    }
    
    // Read dbPassword
    public static String readPreferenceDbPassword() {
        Preferences prefsDbPassword = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(DatabaseParameters.class);

        return  prefsDbPassword.get(DB_PASSWORD, "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the same key for each of the variables. DB_URL, DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD are all empty strings, which is why they overwrite each other. I have two recommendations that might help:

1. Change the values from empty strings to meaningful names for the properties file.
2. Change the names of the constants to make it clear that they are keys. eg change DB_URL to DB_URL_KEY.

Here is a short demo of these ideas. The first time you run it, it will create default values for the three variables, output them and then append an x before saving. Each time you run it, there will be an extra x appended which shows that the values have been retrieved from a file. You will notice that I have applied both recommendations above.

```
import java.util.prefs.*;

public class DatabaseParameters {
    private static final String DB_URL_KEY = "DB_URL";
    private static final String DB_USERNAME_KEY = "DB_USERNAME";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD_KEY = "DB_PASSWORD";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(DatabaseParameters.class);
    
        String dbUrl = prefs.get(DB_URL_KEY, "default url");
        String dbUsername = prefs.get(DB_USERNAME_KEY, "default username");
        String dbPassword = prefs.get(DB_PASSWORD_KEY, "default password");
        
        System.out.println("dbUrl = " + dbUrl);
        System.out.println("dbUsername = " + dbUsername);
        System.out.println("dbPassword = " + dbPassword);
        
        prefs.put(DB_URL_KEY, dbUrl + "x");
        prefs.put(DB_USERNAME_KEY, dbUsername + "x");
        prefs.put(DB_PASSWORD_KEY, dbPassword + "x");
    }
}
```